# How to mark area of geometry going through other geometry?

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry

Imagine you have an area and you put a camera lens / eye at some point above it. I would like to mark on the area what exacly lens / eye can see (it will be eclipse on area). What i have already done is this:

[image: view on area]

Interactive example is available on [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kwf19cbp/1/). In this example you can see a lens pointing to the center of area.

Is there any way I could mark that ellipse on this area with some borders or even different background? I have tried to clip the cone but I'm not able to fill the area of clipped cone (it's empty inside). Any clue how can I achive that?

My both elements are `THREE.Mesh` and area is a `THREE.BoxGeometry` and cone is just a `THREE.ConeGeometry` (both with `THREE.MeshPhongMaterial` material).

Answer (score 0):

Try playing with `material.depthFunc = THREE.EqualDepth` to get a ring where the depth of the cone and the plane Equal each other...

`.depthFunc = THREE.GreaterDepth` to draw only the parts of the cone Behind the plane..
`.depthFunc = THREE.LessDepth` to draw only the parts of the cone In front of the plane..